# Video not displaying in UITableView IOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, video

In my application I'm playing YouTube video. I'm using the `UITableView` because i have array of videos but the problem is in `UITableView` its not Displaying the video but its coming in the `DetailView` of the Cell.

I have used `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController` this classes files to  play the YouTube. I'm `NSObject` because i have the YouTube `ID` in my server from server I'm playing the video 
in my `UITableView`

My Code.

```
   -(void)setDataSource:(videopolitical *)inVideosObj
 {
     self.title.text = inVideosObj.title;
     UIView *videoContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20, 100, 100)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:videoContainerView];

     XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:inVideosObj.video];

     videoPlayerViewController = nil;
     [videoPlayerViewController presentInView:videoContainerView];
     [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
 }
```

I have used the above code its not working in my table please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: try to remove videoPlayerViewController = nil;

Comment: your welcome, but i'll put it as answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove `videoPlayerViewController = nil;`

Answer (score 1):

Here may be issue in first line you define a object

```
 XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:inVideosObj.video];
```

and very next line you are assigning it `nil`

```
videoPlayerViewController = nil;
```

then what you expect here

```
[videoPlayerViewController presentInView:videoContainerView];
```